PCIe x1 risers missing various signals - a hack or a legitimately allowed configuration?
Background
While debugging a system where one of the peripherals was only intermittently present on the bus, I turned my attention to PCIe risers as a culprit. After measuring a few of them I noticed that none of them carry full set of signals between the system board and add-in card slot:

None of the risers carry SMBus (SMCLK, SMDAT)
None of the risers carry JTAG (TCK, TDI, TDO, TMS, TRST#)
Some risers are missing 3v3 on Side A pin 9
All risers have PRSNT1# and PRSNT2# not only tied together, but hardwired to GND
Some risers don't carry CLKREQ# signal
Some risers don't carry WAKE# signal

For the purpose of this question, I was testing risers that use flat cables, like shown below. I deliberately ignored ones using USB-A cables to carry limited set of signals and often used for mining.

PCIe compliant?
It appears that risers cut corners to carry as few lines as possible, which makes me a bit worried about them being actually PCIe complaint, beyond signal integrity.

While reading "PCI Express Card Electromechanical Specification Revision 3.0" document I see that SMBus & JTAG are technically marked as optional for PCIe devices, so removal of these lines shouldn't cause issues as either end cannot expect them to be available. Am I correct here, or not carrying these signals can cause issues with add-in cards?
Should risers tie presence lines to ground by themselves? From my reading of the spec (Figure 3-1) these should only be tied together by the add-in card and grounded only by the host.
CLKREQ# pin appears to be used for L1 PM substates. In my understanding its removal on the riser will cause L1 PM to be limited?
Will severing the WAKE# signal effectively disable wake-up capability of any card plugged via riser?



Yes the JTAG and SMBus are optional and rarely used. There are many motherboards that don't connect them to anything. Lack of these signals will not prevent an add in card (AIC) functioning.

Technically the presence pins should either be both passed through to the other end of the riser, or simply connected together on the risers plug. One is simply grounded by the motherboard, and the other is used to sense presence. In practice grounding them both on the riser will do no harm.

Clock request is used by the AIC to request that it's clock signal be active. Many motherboards if they use them simply connect these together across all sockets such that if any AIC requests a clock, they all get it. I imagine the riser probably ties this pin to ground such that the clock is always active, which may simply result is a tiny amount of extra power usage in sleep. Desktops probably don't implement gating anyway as then have little need for power saving, mobile devices likely do.

Yes if the WAKE signal is not passed through, an AIC won't be able to request wake from sleep  so things like ethernet Wake-On-LAN from an AIC wouldn't be functional.


Many of these risers are simply cheaply made garbage that will not have been tested or certified as PCIe compliant. They just for the most part happen to work for simple use cases. Signal integrity issues usually prevent them working for faster PCIe speeds (many simply work only at gen 1, maybe gen 2 speeds depending on the length).
